# Do anchored containers show up on scans?

Tags: eve-online

If I were to anchor a container in nullsec or lowsec in a safe area as a sort of "poor man's POS", is it possible for another player to find the container without any ships around it?

I know you can use combat probes to scan down ships and dscan to determine the general location of other ships and structures in the system, but do anchored containers show up on any of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anchored containers show up on the directional scan, but not on combat probes. This means that while someone may be able to reason out an approximate location, they have a relatively small chance of actually finding the exact location where you have left a container anchored if the location is chosen wisely.

An anomaly, or other sort of exploration location makes a solid bookmark after the site is despawned. Another good location is a level-2 or level-3 safe site - a bookmark between two celestials is a level-1, warping from that L1 to a third celestial and marking a point creates an L2, and so on. I've not heard of anyone making greater than an L4 safe, because the additional randomness value is low.

Comment: Anchoring in an anomaly is an excellent tip, thanks.

Comment: Another tactic that I use in nullsec is to anchor several containers in "Level 3" or better locations, preferably a little close together.  Place 1 ammo in all of them, and only use one to store your good stuff.  This not only makes it harder to find the one with your good stuff in it, but will throw people off and they may get bored and leave after finding a couple of containers with nothing in it.

Answer (score 0):

D-Scan uses your overview settings. So yes, if you have your overview settings set to see them.